# Character data HTML

Tags: c#-4.0, html-parsing, cdata

I need to show character data in HTML files. It works fine when data is simple, but problem arises when data is similar to tags.

Let me describe my problem.

I am showing data coming from database tables to HTML files (I am creating table to show data).
Now if content in my table is like `<img src ="445521.jpg">` it gives me error while parsing.
since it would try to search image in my system.

In XML, we have `<![CDATA["content"]]>` to rescue, but I dont know what to in HTML for this,
More over I am converting this HTML to PDF. It gives me error even converting to PDF.

Can anybody tell how to create html to make parser understand that the content is Character data ?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please add further clarification of what do you mean by Character data? Is it html entities ?

Comment: I have HTML content stored in SQLLiteDB. I am fetching those contents and showing it in Table. by Character data I mean that browser should interpret as Characters not as HTML tab. For eg if char Content is "<img src ="445521.jpg">" I need to show it as string in table cell not as an image in cell. Let me know if further  clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) (you'll have to `import System.Web`). This will convert the special characters to HTML entities (e.g. `<` → `&lt;`).